# Excel VBA Arguement Not Optional

Tags: vba, excel, arguments

I am trying to write a set of VBA procedure's in Excel.  The purpose for the procedure is to look at the data in a table, average the values in a specific column, and then highlight every value that is above that average.

My dilemma is that I keep getting an "Argument Not Optional" error when I try to run my code.  I fully understand what this error would usually indicate.  However, I can not understand why the two strings I am passing into the procedure are not being accepted?  Thanks in advance for any help..

```
Sub HighlightLarge()

    Call HighlightProductOrders(">", "vbYellow")

End Sub


Sub HighlightProductOrders(FunctionType As String, HighlightColor As String)

    'Delete all previous conditional formatting
     Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

'Make a variable to dynamically cover an entire table range
    Dim FormatTable As Range
    Set FormatTable = Range(Range("AllOrders").Offset(1, 0), Range("AllOrders").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

'Make a variable to calculate average order quantity
    Dim AverageQuantity As Double
    AverageQuantity = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(FormatTable.Columns(2))

'Perform Highlighting based on Sub's params
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    If FunctionType = ">" Then
        Do Until Range("AllOrders").Offset(i, 0) = ""
            If Range("AllOrders").Offset(i, 1) > AverageQuantity Then
                Range("AllOrders").Offset(i, 0).Interior.Color = HighlightColor
                Range("AllOrders").Offset(i, 1).Interior.Color = HighlightColor
                Range("AllOrders").Offset(i, 2).Interior.Color = HighlightColor
            End If
        Loop
    ElseIf FunctionType = "<" Then
        Do Until Range("AllOrders").Offset(i, 0) = ""
            If Range("AllOrders").Offset(i, 1) < AverageQuantity Then
                Range("AllOrders").Offset(i, 0).Interior.Color = HighlightColor
                Range("AllOrders").Offset(i, 1).Interior.Color = HighlightColor
                Range("AllOrders").Offset(i, 2).Interior.Color = HighlightColor
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox "Parameters were not as expected.", vbCritical, "Error!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you can't pass an enumeration member ("vbYellow") as a string.  Which line is the error on?

Comment: I am unable to recreate this. When I setup a test to mimic, it works just fine.

Comment: It doesn't specify a specific line for this error, but given the nature of it and what I've read online, I would assume the error would be on the second line of code where I am calling the procedure.

Comment: Kyle, that kind of goes along with what my confusion is about, I don't see why this code would not work.

Comment: You aren't incrementing the value of `i` in your loops, so you're going around and around the loop forever

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, there may be several bugs that I have yet to work out, because I can't even run the macro :( still trying to figure out the error I posted about.

Comment: Do you have a Sub or Function named `HighlightColor`?

Comment: No, that is one of the arguments (parameters) I am trying to pass into the Sub.

Comment: You say you "assume" the error is on the call to the HighlightProductOrders subroutine - I'm scratching my head trying to understand why the IDE isn't highlighting the current line when you click "Debug" on the error message.

Comment: Do you have any `On Error` statements elsewhere in your code?

Comment: No, what you see is all of my code.

Comment: And you **are** running your code by executing `HighlightLarge` are you?  You aren't just trying to execute `HighlightProductOrders` by, for instance, typing `HighlightProductOrders` within the immediate window, or by using a button pointing to it?

Comment: Yes, for some reason, changing HighlightColor to a Variant instead of a String did the trick.  Not quite sure why, since I used quotations for "vbYellow" regardless, but it works nonetheless..